# Julia: using `Ptr` or `Ref` in combination with ccall and `cfunction`

Tags: pointers, pass-by-reference, julia

My main question is about using pointer to modify content in Julia. I know Julia by itself has this immutable notion that allows for arrays for example to be passed by reference, and if the content of the array is changed properly in a function then we can expect the changed values outside of a function too. But I wanted to ask more about the integration of `cfunction` and `ccall` using `Ref{T}` for changing the content which make variable changes to be visible outside of a specific loop or function.

This is with reference to this topic in the documentation:[Passing pointers for modifying inputs](http://julia-demo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code.html#passing-pointers-for-modifying-inputs)

I was wondering how it is possible to use a Julia defined function to be used in this way. I thought `cfunction` is something that I can convert my Julia functions to C-understandable code, and then I can call them by `ccall`, however I was not successful doing that. Consider the following:

```
function foo(x::Ref{Cint})
    x+=convert(Cint,2)
    return x::Cint
end

y=Ref{Cint}(convert(Cint,2))
c_foo = cfunction(foo, Ref{Cint}, (Ref{Cint},),y)
ccall(:c_foo, Ref{Cint}, (Ref{Cint},), y)
```

And for cfunction I get:

```
MethodError: no method matching cfunction(::#foo, ::Type{Ref{Int32}}, ::Tuple{DataType}, ::Base.RefValue{Int32})
```

All I want to do is to have a variable `y = 2` and inside a function add `2` more, so outside of the function if I print the value of `y`, I get `4`. (I do not mean the answers provided by the arrays.)

Another question I have is that upon solving this question, would it be possible to also use self defined Julia types for this as well?

Comment: `cfunction(foo, Ref{Cint}, (Ref{Cint},),y)` is wrong. It should be cfunction(foo, Ref{Cint}, (Ref{Cint},)). That's why the error. However, when `cfunction` is used like this it converts argument to `Cint` and you get method error when you call `c_foo` not `:c_foo`.